# Send whatsapp messages through php

Tags: php, sockets

I want to send whatsapp messages from my website through php:

I found this resource: https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

But there is no documentation or a how-to, also everywhere it gives me this error:

```
Parse error: 

syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC in 

C:\wamp\www\WhatsAPI-master\src\whatsprot.class.php
```

One file works there, but does not specify a Whatsapp number to send to, the axaxdemo

Many Thanks

Comment: Which PHP Version do you have installed. You need at least 5.3 for late static binding. Also please add the line number and the relevant code from the source file.

Comment: it is version 5.2.6, when I click get more I never got a new version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need **PHP 5.3** at least for [`late static binding`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) (which is related with the error message).

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you get it working with your newer PHP :)

Comment: Only first steps work, after that nothing is clear, I am sure i need a whatsapp password